# What alternatives to pinax exists?

Tags: python, django, pinax

I am planning on transferring my django site to pinax so I dont have to deal with the user registration and what not. Before I make this move, I was wondering what the alternative options are so I dont have to make this transfer twice.

So what alternatives to pinax exists? and which one is your favorite?

Comment: Just make your switch. I have used pinax and nothing yet compared to it.

Comment: cool thanks. Whats your favorite thing about it?

Comment: Pinax is just a collection of Django apps, so really you need to ask about alternatives to particular functionalities. Personally, I don't like the project layout of Pinax, and in fact, I foresee great problems with it's project structure once Django 1.4 hits.

Comment: http://djangopackages.com/ is the site you would want to visit if you want to compare pinax packages for a better guideline

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any alternative, luckily it's active again lately.